# Building a term-document matrix

Tags: r, tm

I have a csv file, whose head is: DATE Alert and OriginatingAddress.
How should I build a term-document matrix based on two columns: DATE and Alert.
The row will have the alert and the column will have the day. The entry indicates the number of occurrences of the alert in a day.

I've tried:

```
library(tm)
myCorpus <- read.csv("alert-sample-data-4-mining.csv")
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(myCorpus$DATE, myCorpus$Alert))
TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
```

But the result is not what I want.

The current result I got is:

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
A term-document matrix (31 terms, 69124 documents)

Non-/sparse entries: 69124/2073720
Sparsity           : 97%
Maximal term length: 9
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

str(myCorpus)
'data.frame':   69124 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ DATEFORMAT        : Factor w/ 31 levels "3/01/2013","3/02/2013",..: 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 ...
 $ Alert             : Factor w/ 88 levels "%BGP-5-ADJCHANGE",..: 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 ...
 $ OriginatingAddress: Factor w/ 98 levels "10.112.36.12",..: 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 ...

Comment: and what you expect to see?

Comment: @aseidlitz I expect to see: The row will have the alert and the column will have the day. In this case: the term-document matrix should be (88 terms, 31 documents), am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're actually asking for a 2-way frequency table, not a term-document matrix:

```
myCorpus <- read.csv("alert-sample-data-4-mining.csv")
table(myCorpus$Alert, myCorpus$DATEFORMAT)
```

Comment: thanks josilber! But I still need to get the result of non-/sparse entries, sparsity, how should I do that?

Comment: Well, if it's really 88 x 31, sparse representation is not going to be that important.